# Is it possible that the App-Scoped user id in Facebook is the same between different apps

Tags: facebook

I learned that the new Graph 2.0 Facebook API will have different user Ids for the same user in different apps, however I wonder if it is possible that a different user will have the same user id in different Apps? So the user id is globally unique across apps or it is just unique in the same app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each combination of an App and an User results in a unique ID. So it's unique in the whole universe, not just over an App.

Stated otherwise: an App-Scoped User ID identifies *both* App *and* User.

If you have multiple apps, you can use the [Business Mapping API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business) to map one app-scoped ID to the other. For that, you need to create a Business Manager and register the apps you own there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wonder if this is officially declared in developer.facebook.com? I tried to find on it but didn't succeed.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's not listed explicitly in these words. But the nature of an "ID" is (often) that it is unique, so that assumptions is a safe one to make.

Comment: It’s not explicitly mentioned in docs AFAIK, but people working for Facebook have confirmed this in the FB developers group multiple times.